# Twisted python, sending lots of data from client to server. No data from server. Data is transferred when I hit 'q' to quit

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, twisted, mediapipe

Here is my Twisted Python client. If I could get it to work at all without a server, I would, but just getting it to work at all has been difficult. I don't really want to send any data from the other server to the client yet.  I just want the client to dump data to the server.  What's happening is that I have to type 'q' to exit the while True loop before any data is sent.  I have been trying to look up frames and found LineReceiver, but I really want a LineSender, I guess.  How do I make this program actually work?  Note that if you run this program, your webcam will turn on and you will see a live video of you. Quit with key 'q' in the video window.  You will need to provide your own server running on localhost:3000.  I think I want some kind of asynchronous thing, but I haven't figured that out yet.  Mainly, I want (non-video) streaming from client to server in python.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_styles as ds
import typing
import numpy as np
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from queue import Queue
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.python import log



mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands.HandLandmark

hand = [[mp_hands.WRIST, "WRIST", "radiocarpal"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_CMC, "THUMB_CMC", "carpometacarpal_1"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_MCP, "THUMB_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_1"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_IP, "THUMB_IP", "carpal_interphalangeal_1"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_TIP, "THUMB_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_1"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_MCP, "INDEX_FINGER_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_2"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_PIP, "INDEX_FINGER_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_2"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_DIP, "INDEX_FINGER_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_2"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_TIP, "INDEX_FINGER_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_2"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_MCP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_3"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_PIP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_3"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_DIP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_3"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_3"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_MCP, "RING_FINGER_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_4"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_PIP, "RING_FINGER_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_4"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_DIP, "RING_FINGER_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_4"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_TIP, "RING_FINGER_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_4"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_MCP, "PINKY_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_5"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_PIP, "PINKY_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_5"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_DIP, "PINKY_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_5"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_TIP, "PINKY_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_5"]]

# Load the MediaPipe Sign Language Detection model
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
holistic = mp_holistic.Holistic()

# Load the MediaPipe Drawing utils for visualization
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

# load MedidPipe hands solutions

# Load the video file
# video_path = "path_to_video_file.mp4"
video_path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class Server(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class ServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Server()

class ClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Client()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print("Connection failed.")
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print("Connection lost.")
        reactor.stop()

# sendMessages()
class Client(protocol.Protocol):
    def startedEvent(self):
        print('started event')

    def performAnAction(self):
        print('performed an action')
        self.bufferSend()
        # reactor.stop()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendMessage("Marker: Start")  # Send marker for the first frame
        self.buffer = []
        self.runRecognizer()


    def sendMessage(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message.encode())
        # self.transport.write(message)

    def bufferSend(self):
        message = "\n".join(self.buffer)+"\n"
        # print(message)
        self.sendMessage(message)
        self.buffer = []

    def bufferMessage(self, message):
        self.buffer.append(message);

    def printHand(self, lmk, joint_string: str, frame):

        self.bufferMessage(f"J:{joint_string}")
        # print(lmk)
        x = lmk.x
        y = lmk.y
        z = lmk.z
        v = lmk.visibility
        shape = frame.shape
        self.bufferMessage(f"X:{x}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"Y:{y}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"Z:{z}")
        relative_x = int(x * shape[1])
        relative_y = int(y * shape[0])
        relative_z = int(z * shape[2])
        self.bufferMessage(f"XR:{relative_x}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"YR:{relative_y}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"ZR:{relative_z}")
        cv2.putText(img=frame, text=joint_string, org=(relative_x, relative_y), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=0.5, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    def runRecognizer(self):
        certainAmount = 5.0  # this is in seconds
        self.bufferMessage("S:D")
        while True:
            if cap.isOpened():
                retval, frame = cap.read()
                if not retval:
                     break

                # Convert the frame to RGB
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                # Detect the signs in the frame
                results = holistic.process(frame_rgb)

                #signs = []
                #if results.pose_landmarks:
                #    sign = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_holistic.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW].visibility
                #    signs.append(sign)

                for connection in mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS:
                    # print(connection)
                    self.bufferMessage(f"F:{connection[0]}")
                    self.bufferMessage(f"T:{connection[1]}")
                if results.left_hand_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                    for landmark in hand:
                        lmk = results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[landmark[0]]
                        self.printHand(lmk, "l_"+landmark[2], frame)
                if results.right_hand_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                    for landmark in hand:
                        lmk = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[landmark[0]]
                        self.printHand(lmk, "r_"+landmark[2], frame)
                if results.pose_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
                    for landmark in range(len(results.pose_landmarks.landmark)):
                        lmk = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[landmark]
                        self.printHand(lmk, str(landmark), frame)

                # Display the frame
                cv2.imshow("Sign Language Detection", frame)
                # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
                reactor.callLater(certainAmount, self.performAnAction)
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

from twisted.internet import task

reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 3000, ClientFactory())
reactor.listenTCP(3002, ServerFactory())
reactor.run()

# # Convert the detected signs to English textual paragraphs
# textual_paragraphs = []
# current_paragraph = ""
# for sign in signs:
#    if sign > 0.5:
#        current_paragraph += " "
#    else:
#        current_paragraph += "."
#        textual_paragraphs.append(current_paragraph)
#        current_paragraph = ""
#
# # Print the English textual paragraphs
# for paragraph in textual_paragraphs:
#    print(paragraph)
```

EDIT:  Here is working code

```
# sgpt --code "translate american sign language signing video to english textual paragraphs"
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_styles as ds
import typing
import numpy as np
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from queue import Queue
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.python import log



mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands.HandLandmark

hand = [[mp_hands.WRIST, "WRIST", "radiocarpal"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_CMC, "THUMB_CMC", "carpometacarpal_1"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_MCP, "THUMB_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_1"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_IP, "THUMB_IP", "carpal_interphalangeal_1"],
[mp_hands.THUMB_TIP, "THUMB_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_1"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_MCP, "INDEX_FINGER_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_2"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_PIP, "INDEX_FINGER_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_2"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_DIP, "INDEX_FINGER_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_2"],
[mp_hands.INDEX_FINGER_TIP, "INDEX_FINGER_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_2"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_MCP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_3"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_PIP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_3"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_DIP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_3"],
[mp_hands.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP, "MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_3"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_MCP, "RING_FINGER_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_4"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_PIP, "RING_FINGER_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_4"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_DIP, "RING_FINGER_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_4"],
[mp_hands.RING_FINGER_TIP, "RING_FINGER_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_4"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_MCP, "PINKY_MCP", "metacarpophalangeal_5"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_PIP, "PINKY_PIP", "carpal_proximal_interphalangeal_5"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_DIP, "PINKY_DIP", "carpal_distal_interphalangeal_5"],
[mp_hands.PINKY_TIP, "PINKY_TIP", "carpal_distal_phalanx_5"]]

# Load the MediaPipe Sign Language Detection model
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
holistic = mp_holistic.Holistic()

# Load the MediaPipe Drawing utils for visualization
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

# load MedidPipe hands solutions

# Load the video file
# video_path = "path_to_video_file.mp4"
video_path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

#class myServer(protocol.Protocol):
#    def dataReceived(self, data):
#        self.transport.write(data)

#class myServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
#    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
#        return myServer()

class myClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return myClient()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print("Connection failed.")
        #reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print("Connection lost.")
        #reactor.stop()

# sendMessages()
class myClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def startedEvent(self):
        print('started event')

    def performAnAction(self):
        # print('performed an action')
        if cap.isOpened():
            retval, frame = cap.read()
            if not retval:
                reactor.callLater(0, self.performAnAction)
            else:
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                # Detect the signs in the frame
                results = holistic.process(frame_rgb)

                #signs = []
                #if results.pose_landmarks:
                #    sign = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_holistic.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW].visibility
                #    signs.append(sign)

                for connection in mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS:
                    # print(connection)
                    self.bufferMessage(f"F:{connection[0]}")
                    self.bufferMessage(f"T:{connection[1]}")
                if results.left_hand_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                    for landmark in hand:
                        lmk = results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[landmark[0]]
                        self.printHand(lmk, "l_"+landmark[2], frame)
                if results.right_hand_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                    for landmark in hand:
                        lmk = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[landmark[0]]
                        self.printHand(lmk, "r_"+landmark[2], frame)
                if results.pose_landmarks:
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
                    for landmark in range(len(results.pose_landmarks.landmark)):
                        lmk = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[landmark]
                        self.printHand(lmk, str(landmark), frame)

                # Display the frame
                cv2.imshow("Sign Language Detection", frame)
                # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    self.bufferSend()
                    print("Stopping")
                    reactor.stop()
        else:
            print("Video died")
            reactor.callLater(0, self.performAnAction)
        self.bufferSend()
        # tail "recursion"
        reactor.callLater(0, self.performAnAction)

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendMessage("Marker: Start")  # Send marker for the first frame
        self.buffer = []
        self.runRecognizer()


    def sendMessage(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message.encode())
        # self.transport.write(message)

    def bufferSend(self):
        message = "\n".join(self.buffer)+"\n"
        # print(message)
        self.sendMessage(message)
        self.buffer = []

    def bufferMessage(self, message):
        self.buffer.append(message);

    def printHand(self, lmk, joint_string: str, frame):

        self.bufferMessage(f"J:{joint_string}")
        # print(lmk)
        x = lmk.x
        y = lmk.y
        z = lmk.z
        v = lmk.visibility
        shape = frame.shape
        self.bufferMessage(f"X:{x}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"Y:{y}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"Z:{z}")
        relative_x = int(x * shape[1])
        relative_y = int(y * shape[0])
        relative_z = int(z * shape[2])
        self.bufferMessage(f"XR:{relative_x}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"YR:{relative_y}")
        self.bufferMessage(f"ZR:{relative_z}")
        cv2.putText(img=frame, text=joint_string, org=(relative_x, relative_y), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=0.5, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    def runRecognizer(self):
        certainAmount = 5.0  # this is in seconds
        self.bufferMessage("S:D")
        reactor.callLater(0, self.performAnAction)
        # self.transport.loseConnection()

from twisted.internet import task

reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 3000, myClientFactory())
# reactor.listenTCP(3002, myServerFactory())
reactor.run()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# # Convert the detected signs to English textual paragraphs
# textual_paragraphs = []
# current_paragraph = ""
# for sign in signs:
#    if sign > 0.5:
#        current_paragraph += " "
#    else:
#        current_paragraph += "."
#        textual_paragraphs.append(current_paragraph)
#        current_paragraph = ""
#
# # Print the English textual paragraphs
# for paragraph in textual_paragraphs:
#    print(paragraph)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's happening is that I have to type 'q' to exit the while True loop before any data is sent

Twisted programs are mainly single-threaded by default.  In particular, all of your application code will execute in a single thread - alongside the reactor.  It is a "cooperative multitasking" system - code runs until it gives up control, then someone else gets scheduled and runs until it gives up control, and so on.

The `while True` holds on to control and prevents anything else from happening, including any data from being sent.

Get rid of the `while True` and schedule iterations of your loop in a cooperative way - for example, with `reactor.callLater` or perhaps the slightly higher-level `twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall`.

Also, make sure you avoid any blocking calls in the body of what was your `while` loop (and everywhere else).  For example, `cv2.waitKey` *could* block for a while if called with certain arguments and this will also prevent the rest of your application code or the reactor from running.  I think `cv2.waitKey(1)` may be more or less safe since I think the 1 is the number of
milliseconds to wait but you should confirm this - and you may also want to deal with input non-blockingly anyway, for example using `twisted.internet.stdio`.

- Get rid of any blocking operations from the body of the loop.  For example, if `

Comment: Can i call callLater with a 0 delay, or will that call recursively?  I’ve already faced some recursion in a sample app.

Comment: Looks like twisted.internet.stdio does not work well on Win32, so I hope that what i have will work.

Comment: It looks like I’ve already got callLater in my loop, so I just need to put the body of my loop in  performAnAction, then callLater in the performAnAction method as well

Comment: LoopingCall didn't work for me, I am editing the question with an answer!